# How to Install JavaFX with openjdk-11-jdk?

Tags: 18.04, java, javafx

I am trying to build [this jlink demo](https://github.com/steve-perkins/jlink-demo) with Java 11.

I installed the OpenJDK 11.

The build process fails when it attempts to link against javafx.

I think I have the javafx packages installed:

```
> libopenjfx-java/bionic,bionic,now 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 all
> [installed,automatic] libopenjfx-java-doc/bionic,bionic
> 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 all libopenjfx-jni/bionic,now 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
> amd64 [installed,automatic] openjfx/bionic,now 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
> amd64 [installed] openjfx-source/bionic,bionic 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 all
```

How do I install JavaFX such that it is connected to Java 11? I understand that Java 11 decoupled JavaFX, but I believe it can still be used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed OpenJDK-11 (and JavaFX) from the bionic-repository try this build instead: https://jdk.java.net/11/ for the Oracle-build of the OpenJDK and https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ for JavaFX respectively OpenJFX (https://openjfx.io/).

I also installed OpenJDK with `apt` first, but the bionic-package versioned with 11 seems to be a 10 build.

After you extracted the OpenJFX-package you can use the `lib` folder of the SDK or the `jmods` folder, respectively for the `--module-path` mentioned in the `build.gradle` of your demo.